# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve but module is in node_modules

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, eslint

I'm having a problem with the build prod of my application.
The build fail with an error  however everything is generated by the build. It fails but everything is fine except the following error.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types' in 'D:/path/to/a/file'
```

Here is the content of the mentioned file

```
import { Calendar, Event as MicrosoftEvent } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
```

If I remove this line in VS Code I can no more import automatically.

When i run 'ng serve' and 'ng test' it works perfectly. Only the following command fails

```
ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer
```

@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types is a dev dependency (it's the same for dependecy) and I'm using version 1.8.0.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure how angular builds but you seem to specify that you are building for production at which point dev dependencies are not bundled. Does the problem remain when moving @microsoft/microsoft-graph-types to the set of normal (not dev) dependencies?

Comment: Yes the problem is still here

Comment: does it build correctly after removing buildOptimizer?

Comment: Without buildOptimizer the problem persists

Comment: I've done a ng build --prod --delete-output-path and I have this error FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `eslint (import/no-unresolved)`